# Homology of subgroups

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-topology

I'm learning about homology of groups right now and I have a general question about homology of subgroups. I know that we won't get "homology of subgroup is subgroup of homology", that wouldn't make sense for several reasons. But, I am trying to figure out what *can* be said. If $J\leq G$ is a subgroup and $X$ is a $K(G,1)$, then by Galois correspondence we have a covering space $p:Y\to X$ such that $\pi_1(Y)\cong J$. Moreover, since $X$ and $Y$ have the same universal cover, $Y$ is a $K(J,1)$. So the homology of $J$ is by definition the homology of $Y$. We know that $H_*(\cdot)$ on topological spaces is a functor, so we have a map on homology $p_*:H_*(Y)\to H_*(X)$. But what does $p$ do exactly?

EDIT: A quick example. Consider $G=\langle x| \ \rangle$. A $K(G,1)$ is the unit circle, which we may assume is embedded in $\mathbb{C}$. Then the subgroup $J=\langle 2x \rangle$ corresponds to the covering $p:S^1\to S^1$ by $z^2$. I am not sure what $p_*$ does, but I already know that $H_*(J)\cong H_*(G)$. So it seems like in order to start talking about this general problem we need to start adding constraints: like choose $J\leq G$ with $J\ncong G$.

Comment: It is hard to understand what you're specific question is, $p$ is a covering space. What is meant by "what does $p$ do"?

Comment: The paragraph above shows that if $J\leq G$, then there is a map on homology $p_*:H_*(J)\to H_*(G)$. That's all I've been able to cook up. Are we able to say anything more about this map? As I mentioned, it is kind of a general question.

Comment: You are not going to have much to say. Here is something, at least. It is a famous (but quite nontrivial) theorem that if $J \leq G$ are finite groups, then if $p_*$ is an isomorphism, then $J = G$.

Comment: For general remarks in that area, take a look at the Hochschild-Serre spectral sequence or the transfer map. As the former shows, it's not a simple relation.